# Collect Java8 IntStream into Deque interface

Tags: collections, java-8

How to collect Java8 IntStream into [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface? 
I can perform this kind of operation with List like that:

```
List<Integer> integerList = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)
                                     .boxed()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't collect to an interface, but to an implementation of it (as long as it is a `Collection`) via `Collectors.toCollection`

```
 Deque<Integer> d = IntStream.of(1, 2)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
```

Comment: fast like a bolt ^_^

Answer (score 7):

use `Collectors.toCollection` to specify the collection you want, example:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
```

or any other implementation of the [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface.